# How to force GNOME using software rendering

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have a graphics card installed. There's some problem when I enable the GPU acceleration option. Is there any way to force GNOME Desktop Environment, using software rendering only, just like absolutely no OpenGL acceleration is available?